# Configuring file logging in Azure to write to a specific LocalStorage defined in LocalResources

Tags: logging, azure, nlog

I have logging setup with NLog using nlog.config that is pointed to by web.config. In this nlog.config file I need to place a line like this:

```
fileName="ApplicationLog.txt"
```

I want the log entries to go to this file.

My ServiceDefinition.csdef file contains this:

```
<LocalResources>
  <LocalStorage name="DiagnosticStore" sizeInMB="20000" cleanOnRoleRecycle="false" />
  <LocalStorage name="LogStorage" cleanOnRoleRecycle="false" sizeInMB="8192" />
</LocalResources>
```

I want the logging to go to a subfolder of the root to which LogStorage points. This is something like this on a deployed Azure VM:

```
C:\Resources\Directory\ec1b400c7e58640a8b874035ba9196c.Services.LogStorage\logs/ApplicationLog.txt
```

If I hard code this into the nlog.config file, the logs are successfully written to there. This is my Target tag inside the config file:

```
<target name="App" xsi:type="File"  
lineEnding="Default" autoFlush="true" keepFileOpen="false"  
fileName="ApplicationLog.txt">
```

When fileName is set to ApplicationLog.txt the file does not appear anywhere on the server. No logs are written.

My diagnostics.wadcfg contains the magic period:

```
<DataSources>
  <DirectoryConfiguration container="telemetry-logs" directoryQuotaInMB="4096">
    <LocalResource name="LogStorage" relativePath=".\archive" />
  </DirectoryConfiguration>
</DataSources>
```

This is how Azure diagnostics finds the log files, matching the files written by NLog to my LocalStorage.

What do I put in the Target tag inside the nlog.config file to get the root of the folder represented by the LocalStorage tag?

Comment: have you come across [this](http://blog.elastacloud.com/2011/02/18/custom-azure-nlog-integration-with-azure-diagnostics-sdk-1-3-using-nuget/), [that](http://awkwardcoder.blogspot.co.uk/2012/03/getting-nlog-working-with-azure-is-as.html) and [this](https://github.com/chrisdostert/NLog.Config.Azure) articles? Do they help you?

Comment: I'd seen 2 of those articles. We are writing to a file so we can upload into Blob storage not table storage, something that was recommended by Microsoft given the scale of our app is huge. One article hits the nail by logging to C:\Andy, which is clearly unacceptable in an Azure server! However, giving nlog a hard coded drive and path does work as I noted. I don't want to hard code to a drive/path that could easily move on deployment.

Comment: Well, not supported officialy, and yes may change in the future (although survived quite a lot major updates) - Drive C: is pretty stable. You can hardcode a path within C: and work with that. The only trick is to create the folder via an elevated start-up task and give it full access to all accounts in the system.

Answer (score 1):

One way that I can suggest (never tested though) is to use custom environment variable.

The Azure SDK gives you the possibility to [define custom environment variables](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/gg432991.aspx). You can then use [XPath to get setting values](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh404006.aspx).

Now I wonder whether you can define a variable `NLogPath` with `RoleInstanceValue` equals to `/RoleEnvironment/CurrentInstance/LocalResources/LocalResource[@name='LogStorage']/@path`

Definition shall look something like:

```
  <Runtime>
     <Environment>
        <Variable name="NLogPath">
                <RoleInstanceValue xpath="/RoleEnvironment/CurrentInstance/LocalResources/LocalResource[@name='LogStorage']/@path" />
        </Variable>
     </Environment>
  </Runtime>
```

Now try configuring the NLog like this:

```
<target name="App" xsi:type="File"  
lineEnding="Default" autoFlush="true" keepFileOpen="false"  
fileName="${environment:variable=NLogPath}\ApplicationLog.txt">
```

Comment: Unfortunately setting environment variables does not work because nlog does not get the value of environment variables when they are defined in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/gg432991.aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh404006.aspx
I chose an alternative strategy; I set the current folder in code when the worker role starts, then used a fixed, relative path in nlog.config

Comment: or, if NLog is extensible enough, you can write an extension that will read Azure Environment for Local Resource Root Path. Something that [I did for Unity (Enterprise Application Block)](http://uasi.codeplex.com/)

Comment: The correct way to access environment variables is not using percent signs, it is like this: ${environment:variable=NLogPath}

Comment: OK, so does it work with what I suggested and replacing the %NLogPath% with ${environment:variable=NLogPath} ? If it works, please mark the answer as accepted.

Comment: If I do this: ${environment:variable=USERNAME} then the filename can contain that environment variable. What doesn't work is to set the environment variable within the role instance. Your code appears good according to other sources but I couldn't get it to work.